# How to resolve Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: in xcode

Tags: macos, afnetworking

I am getting below error

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFNetworkReachabilityManager", referenced from:
>       objc-class-ref in WindowController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I am Developing for OSX(10.9) as Target OS version.It is an OSX application. What should be my architecture settings inorder to resolve this issue. I had also added $inherited in Linker flags. I am completely lost and working on this cluelessly since many days. Any help is appreciable

Comment: I included AFnetworking using pods.